# Why everything but ssh is blocked? (from within and out of lan)

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, firewalld

It's a Ubuntu server 20.04.2, at home network. Used mostly for testing and non-destructive experiments (php, python study, virtual machines, etc), used as a  headless machine next to my working pc.

Problem appeared after installing iRedMail. Obviously, I uninstalled it immediately and purged all components. After I saw that didn't fix it I tried restoring etc folder from a week old backup. Surprisingly, that didn't kill the OS and everything works, except... still, everything but ssh is blocked.

Here is nmap output:

```
Host is up (0.0000090s latency).
Not shown: 985 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
110/tcp  open  pop3
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
143/tcp  open  imap
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
465/tcp  open  smtps
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
2222/tcp open  EtherNetIP-1
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
8333/tcp open  bitcoin
```

iptables -v -x -n -L output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 866112 packets, 1230088617 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2056   148363 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 453277 packets, 38601280 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       2       84 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain FWDI_public_log (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_post (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_pre (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_post (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_pre (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (0 references)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain IN_public (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_deny (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_post (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_pre (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Can't connect to anything but ssh.
no xrdp, no smbd.
Ping is ok, 0% lost.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are your attempts to connect from the same LAN or from elsewhere on the internet?

Comment: Details been added.

Comment: Your problems are not due to your iptables rule set. They block nothing.

Comment: Any ideas what can cause that blockage ?